# How to properly configure UITableView custom cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to create a custom cell for my UITableView, but whether I use the cell with the identifier from storyboard, or completely create my own cell, for some reason the data loads but it only 1 cell when I scroll. It only shows 1 cell one at a time. Here is how I am currently trying to do it:

```
 let cell = UITableViewCell()
let cellTextLabel = UILabel()
let cellDetailLabel = UILabel()
let imageView = UIImageView()
let phImage = UIImage(named: "CryptiXJustX")

 func configureCustomCell() {
    cell.addSubview(imageView)
    imageView.backgroundColor = .clear
    imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    imageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80).isActive = true
    imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80).isActive = true
    imageView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.leftAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    imageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    cell.addSubview(cellTextLabel)
    cellTextLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    cellTextLabel.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.rightAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    cellTextLabel.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.contentView.rightAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
    cellTextLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.contentView.topAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    cellTextLabel.textColor = .white
    cell.addSubview(cellDetailLabel)
    cellDetailLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    cellDetailLabel.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.rightAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    cellDetailLabel.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.contentView.rightAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
    cellDetailLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cellTextLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    cellDetailLabel.textColor = .white
    cellDetailLabel.font = cellDetailLabel.font.withSize(12)
    cellDetailLabel.numberOfLines = 3

    cell.backgroundColor = .clear
    cell.textLabel?.textColor = .white
    cell.detailTextLabel?.textColor = .white

    imageView.image = phImage
}

 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

     var index = indexPath.row
    if contentData.count > 0 {
    cellTextLabel.text = contentData[index].title
    cellDetailLabel.text = contentData[index].text
        return cell
    } else {
        return cell
    }
}
```

I `configureCustomCell()` in `ViewDidLoad()`, I feel it has something to do with `cellforRowAt` method but I am not sure.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

     view.backgroundColor = .clear

    configureCustomCell()

    NewsAPI.shared.getData(arr: true) { (success) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {

            self.contentData = NewsAPI.shared.contentData[0].posts
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
    }
```

Thank you.

Comment: You only have a single cell instance. That's not how it needs to be. Please find a good table view tutorial and read up on the proper way to dequeue a reusable cell.

Comment: Two more things. First, try using a *normal* cell with just some text in it - make sure you're not doing something wrong elsewhere in your code. (2) Most ties when I see the term *custom table cell* I think subclassing. Yes, I'm "old-school" but I've yet to seen a "Swiftier" way of doing custom table cells than subclassing `UITableViewCell`.

Comment: if you want to create custom TableViewCell then you must register that class with tableView like this 
    self.tableView.registerClass(Cell.self as AnyClass, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")

Comment: @dfd Thank you, the subclass way is definitely much cleaner and easy to understand, had not thought to do that as I don’t have much experience but this is very good to know. +Abid that worked well thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is because you are using on single instance cell for the whole tableview. This is an incorrect way to load your data into your UITableView

But you can try use instead of:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var index = indexPath.row
    if contentData.count > 0 {
        cellTextLabel.text = contentData[index].title
        cellDetailLabel.text = contentData[index].text

        return cell
    } else {
        return cell
    }
}
```

Try to use like this way:

```
class MyCell: UITableViewCell {
    let cellTextLabel = UILabel()
    let cellDetailLabel = UILabel()
    let imageView = UIImageView()
    let phImage = UIImage(named: "CryptiXJustX")

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        contentView.addSubview(imageView)
        imageView.backgroundColor = .clear
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        imageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80).isActive = true
        imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80).isActive = true
        imageView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leftAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
        imageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        contentView.addSubview(cellTextLabel)
        cellTextLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        cellTextLabel.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.rightAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
        cellTextLabel.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.contentView.rightAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
        cellTextLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.contentView.topAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
        cellTextLabel.textColor = .white
        contentView.addSubview(cellDetailLabel)
        cellDetailLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        cellDetailLabel.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.rightAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
        cellDetailLabel.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.contentView.rightAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
        cellDetailLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cellTextLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
        cellDetailLabel.textColor = .white
        cellDetailLabel.font = cellDetailLabel.font.withSize(12)
        cellDetailLabel.numberOfLines = 3

        contentView.backgroundColor = .clear
        contentView.textLabel?.textColor = .white
        contentView.detailTextLabel?.textColor = .white
    }
}
```

On you ViewDidLoad:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // if you are not using storyboard, make sure you are registered the cell ID
    self.tableView!.register("CellID", forCellReuseIdentifier: tableReuseIdentifier)
}
```

Finally:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: 'CellID', for: indexPath) as! MyCell

    cell.imageView.image = phImage
    cell.cellTextLabel.text = contentData[indexPath.row].title
    cell.cellDetailLabel.text = contentData[indexPath.row].text

    return cell
}
```

Comment: This works but I am getting some overlapping, once I scroll the items become unreadable as it seems to put cells on top of cells

Comment: It's true, i'm sorry. Actually it's still the incorrect way. The correct way is creating your own UITableViewCell subclass, there you will can add you labels, images and properties. Then you can use, doing cast over dequeueReuseTableCell. I can send you some example classes to help you by email if you want.

Answer (score 1):

Create the custom UITableViewCell as below

```
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {
}
```

And in controller viewDidLoad you will register the above cell as below

```
tableView.registerClass(CustomCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "CustomCell")
```

Comment: There's more to it than just this. This answer needs a lot more detail.